# Trouble with differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've the following differential equation

\begin{equation}
\dot{y}/y= - \lambda^{\ast} [\log(y/y^{\ast})]
\end{equation}

where $y(t)$ is function of time, $\lambda^{\ast}$ is a constant and $y^{\ast}$ is the steady state value of $y$.

I proceeded as follows

I multiplied the left and right hand side by $dt$ and divided the left and right hand side by $log(y/y^{\ast})$:

$\frac{dy}{y ~\log(\frac{y}{y^{\ast}})} = - \lambda^{\ast} dt$

Then, by setting $\frac{1}{y}dy=dx$ and $\log(y/y^{\ast})=x$, I wrote, after integrating

$\int \frac{1}{x} dx= - \lambda^{\ast} \int dt$

$ \log(|\log(y) - \log(y^{\ast})|) = - \lambda^{\ast}t + C$

Taking exp:

$\log(y(t))= \log(y^\ast) + \log(y(0)) e^{-\lambda t}$ ,

with $\log(y(0)) \equiv e^C$

However, the textbook's result says:

\begin{equation}
\log(y(t))= (1- e^{- \lambda^{\ast}t})\log(y^\ast) + \log(y(0)) e^{-\lambda^{\ast} t}
\end{equation}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was I typo. Btw, I'm still missing $(1- e^{\lambda^{\ast}t}) $ in front of $log(y^{\ast})$. How can I infer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you obtain $\log(x)=-\lambda^\ast t + C$ then you applied the exponetial funcion and get $x(t) = Ce^{-\lambda^\ast t}$, remmeber that you define $x(t)=\log(y/y^\ast)$. Hence $\log(y(t)/y^\ast) = Ce^{-\lambda^\ast t}$, or equivalently,
\begin{equation*}
\log(y(t)) = Ce^{-\lambda^\ast t}- \log(y^\ast).
\end{equation*}
Finally evaluate the solution at $t=0$ to find the value of $C$, and you get the equation you wanted.